# Ajax with javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have problem with get the returned data from a link . It is not working .
I have search more and try everything but it still not working . could anyone help me .
the link : https://www.routingnumbers.info/api/data.json?rn=13442323
my code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
 var request = $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                data: "rn=" + "54455445",
                url: "https://www.routingnumbers.info/api/data.json",
                success: function(data) {
alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatusA: " + status);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert("Data: " + "Err" + "\nStatus: " + status);
                    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    request.abort();
                }
            });


        $.get("demo_test.asp", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: change the data string in the ajax request to `{'rn':'54455445'}`

Comment: why vote down ? can anyone explain ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, I'd always advise using proper JSON formatting in ajax requests. The data attribute should be an object instead of a variable assignment. In the end, it doesn't actually matter; the request will complete with either format. It's always nice to look at consistently-formatted code, though. Regardless, the major problems that were causing the request to fail were the type of request you were making and its origin.

In the code you provided, you were making a request to an `https` address. The page you were requesting from, however, was not an `https` page, but an `http` page instead. This caused the request to return the error `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`.

If you fix that, however, the request still won't complete successfully. This is because XMLHttpRequest doesn't allow requests to websites that aren't the same as the one that you are requesting from. For example, you could request content from `routingnumbers.info` if you're running the script from within `routingnumbers.info` itself, but not if you're running it from elsewhere. This can be fixed by specifying the request as a `jsonp` request instead of the default `json` request.

```
$("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            async: true,
            url: "http://www.routingnumbers.info/api/data.json",
            data: {
                rn: "54455445"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var array = [];
                $.each(data, function(index, value){
                    array.push(index + ': ' + value);    
                });
                alert(array.join("\n"));
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert(data.statusText);
            }
        });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1nx6f9e/1/)

Hope this is helpful!